# Rails assets are not being compiled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have migrate rails appication from `rails 2.3.14` to `rails 3.2.6`.
I copied assets from `public` to 'app/assets' and In `application.rb`, i set

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

In layout i am including stylesheets as

```
= stylesheet_link_tag 'reset', 'text', '960', 'main', 'articles', :cache => true
```

Application boots up correctly by 'rails server' command.

when i go to homepage, i get the following error.

```
No such file or directory - Asset file not found at '/home/ramiz/projects/hq_channel/public/stylesheets/home/ramiz/projects/hq_channel/app/assets/stylesheets/reset.css'
```

It appears to have concatenated the path to the folder twice before looking for the file.

what i am doing wrong??

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`app/assetes` should be `app/assets`

Comment: MIk, that was typo, i edited the question. Please see again :)

Answer (score 0):

Read this. All of it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

If you are precompiling assets, you need to declare anything besides the application one in the configuration. For instance from documentation:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

And in your application.css

```
*= require reset
*= require text
.. etc ..
```

And in `<head>`

```
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```